# What was Groot doing during the fight between Drax and Ronan?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

On Knowhere, Drax calls Ronan, and just after he arrives, the Guardians steal some pods. Rocket tells Groot he can't fit in the pod and to wait for him until he gets back. Drax then attacks Ronan. Where was Groot? I've been wondering why Groot didn't help Drax during the fight. Afterwards, Groot saves Drax by pulling him out of the yellow liquid and reviving him.

Comment: Presumably "waiting here".